# How to get WorkItem in tfs plugin (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, typescript, tfs

I'm writing a small plugin (report) for the TFS 2013 with [this manual](https://gbeeming.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/tfs-js-extension-using-typescript/). 
i get current user(user id) and other user information like this:

`this.TFS.Host.TfsContext.getDefault().currentIdentity.id`.
But i cant get workItem by id. I tried use `this.TFS.WorkItems`, but there is no `get` or `find` methods.

How can i get workItem by id??

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
var itemID = workitem.getLinks[0].linkData.ID;

workItem.store.beginGetWorkItem(linkedWorkItemId) {

    // ...
};
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but how can i get `workItem` or `store`?? i have tfs object but there is nothing like Store or WorkItems: https://gyazo.com/050d40e4670da87d57b221a693745c5f

Comment: If you want to get work item by ID, you could use WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem method, for JS. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore(v=vs.120).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=jscript#code-snippet-1) . A similar question for your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a4fc28f-00e2-441c-b845-7a4e0a389487/tfs-2015-workitemgetworkitem-is-undefined-in-web-access?forum=tfsworkitemtracking

Comment: Try to use this.TFS_WorkitemTracking and worktiem manger just like the sample in  this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660203/Tfs-Js-Extension-using-TypeScript